# Proof help number theory

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ be nonempty. If $\sup(A) \in A$ then $\sup(A)$ is the largest
element of $A$, i.e., $\sup(A) = \max(A)$. Conversely, if $A$ has a largest element then

> $$\max(A) = \sup(A)$$

and $\sup(A) \in A$.

Can anyone help me with this statement?

Comment: What is $R$? The real numbers?

Comment: yes the real numbers

Comment: Let $\sup A = s$. By definition $s\ge x$ for all $x\in A$. This is the definition of a maximum provided $s\in A$, which you are given.

Answer (score 1):

$\Longrightarrow$

If $\sup A = m \in A$, then $A$ is bounded above by $m$. Consequently, for all $x \in A$, $x \leq m$. This is the definition of the maximum.

$\Longleftarrow$

Let $\max(A) = t$. $A$ is bounded above by $t$. If $\sup A = m \neq t$, then $m<t$. But this is absurd, since $t \in A$ which would imply $m$ is not an upper bound of $A$.